# DIV with two tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know how to deal with more than one class in div but I never seen something like that:

```
<div data-reactroot>
</div>
```

It is not a class, not a ID it looks just like multiple tag. How am I supposed to select it with jQuery? I tried

```
$('div data-reactroot');
```

But it seems that I'm not even close to it.

Comment: `"div[data-reactroot]"` - it's an *attribute* of the tag.

Comment: As others have said, it's a data attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: classes are when you have class="myClass" then you have to search with .myClass. If you specify an ID (must be unique for the whole DOM) you can search it with #ID. for attributes the others have already answered :)

Answer (score 8):

Try to use [`has attribute selector`](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) at this contex,

```
$('div[data-reactroot]');
```

Since `data-reactroot` is an attribute of div element.

Comment: Thanks, I would never think that it is an attribute, it doesn't even look like, why it doesn't have `="value"`

Comment: @stevenhawkingsbiggestfan It is a valid form of setting an attribute to element. There is no compulsion that it should have a value.

Comment: @stevenhawkingsbiggestfan if you're satisfied with this answer, you should mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2):

As written, it is an attribute and here is how to get it with plain javascript using the [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)

```
var elem = document.querySelector('div[data-reactroot]');
```